# Storyboards not updating when app updates on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am about to upload a new version of my app to appstore, I did some CoreData migrations so I thought It'd be better to check if everything works by installing the current version from AppStore and deploying the newer version from XCode. To my surprise, all the storyboard changes that I made since are not present when I deploy the app on iOS7.For Example I changed class of a VC in my storyboard but iOS creates the instance of previous class (which was in the previous version). Same goes for autolayout constraints i.e. newer ones are not present. But it works fine on iOS8+. 
This problem is only when I update the app. Clean install works fine. I have made like a thousand changes in more than 5 storyboards.

So far if I change the name of the storyboard it starts working. All the new VCs are also working, Only the ones which have been updated are problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It turns out it might be a bug in XCode 7.2 SDK.
I just compiled the application with XCode 7.1 SDK and everything started working.